# I want to convert a large csv file into hdf5 file using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, hdf5

I have a very large csv file and I want to convert it hdf5 file in a fast way.

My data looks like this but has millions of data points.

I want to group it by 'Date' and 'Name'. That is, I want this hierarchy '/Date/Name'.

```
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date1   f1  1   1   11
date1   f1  2   2   12
date1   f1  3   3   13
date2   f1  1   4   14
date2   f1  2   5   15
date2   f1  3   6   16
date3   f1  1   7   17
date3   f1  2   8   18
date3   f1  3   9   19
date1   f2  1   10  20
date1   f2  2   11  21
date1   f2  3   12  22
date2   f2  1   13  23
date2   f2  2   14  24
date2   f2  3   15  25
date3   f2  1   16  26
date3   f2  2   17  27
date3   f2  3   18  28
date1   f3  1   19  29
date1   f3  2   20  30
date1   f3  3   21  31
date2   f3  1   22  32
date2   f3  2   23  33
date2   f3  3   24  34
date3   f3  1   25  35
date3   f3  2   26  36
date3   f3  3   27  37
```

I have tried the following.

- I convert the csv file to a hdf file line by line. It worked but it takes tons of time. I want a faster way.
- I tried groupby function. It seemed to work but generated an unexpected outcome.

**My Code:**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

my_csv = dd.read_csv('E:/Hdf5_test.csv',blocksize=100) #I set blocksize to 100 in order to make multiple partitions.

def make_hdf(df):
    g_name = 'Date'+ str(df.iloc[0,0]) + 'Firm' + str(df.iloc[0,0]) #This is the key
    store.append(g_name, df, data_columns=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)

hdf_file = 'E:/output.hdf5'
store = pd.HDFStore(hdf_file, mode='a')

order.groupby(['Date','Name']).apply(make_hdf, meta = dict(my_csv.dtypes)).compute()

store.close()

I want a hdf5 file like this:

key = '/date1/f1/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date1   f1  1   1   11
date1   f1  2   2   12
date1   f1  3   3   13

key = '/date2/f1/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date2   f1  1   4   14
date2   f1  2   5   15
date2   f1  3   6   16

key = '/date3/f1/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date3   f1  1   7   17
date3   f1  2   8   18
date3   f1  3   9   19

key = '/date1/f2/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date1   f2  1   10  20
date1   f2  2   11  21
date1   f2  3   12  22

key = '/date2/f2/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date2   f2  1   13  23
date2   f2  2   14  24
date2   f2  3   15  25

key = '/date3/f2/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date3   f2  1   16  26
date3   f2  2   17  27
date3   f2  3   18  28

key = '/date1/f3/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date1   f3  1   19  29
date1   f3  2   20  30
date1   f3  3   21  31

key = '/date2/f3/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date2   f3  1   22  32
date2   f3  2   23  33
date2   f3  3   24  34

key = '/date3/f3/'
Date    Name    No  Price   Quantity
date3   f3  1   25  35
date3   f3  2   26  36
date3   f3  3   27  37
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did I get it right, that you want to store each portion of data under it's own key like key='/date3/f2/'? If so, why do you need that, because I guess it will require looping over the groups and require lots of time. If you use the data with pandas later, you could rather filter the dataframe then, which would most likely be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you really like to split the record, you can try the following code:

```
for (group_date, group_name), group in df.groupby(['Date', 'Name']):
    g_name= f'/{group_date}/{group_name}/'
    print(hdf_key, group.shape)
    store.append(g_name, group, data_columns=True, compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

But it probably will still consume a lot of time, if you have many groups to process. If you read the hdf5 file later from pandas, you could maybe filter the file after reading it in pandas. This probably will be faster. Depending on how often you do it and if you have to read everything anyways or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason why I want to do this is to modify the file. I have another file and I need to extract some info from it and add it to the first file. I should match them by date and firm name. I thought it would be faster to group by date and firm. Is filtering faster than what I try to do?